# Error when accessing a SQlite database in android studio

Tags: java, mysql, database, sqlite, android-studio

Following my last post i was using SQLiteOpenHelper to access a pre-populated sqlite database and someone suggested i use SQLAssetHelper so i found a guide followed it and tried to implement it but i am still getting errors.

like: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I know what a null pointer exception is in most cases but dont understand it in this context as i am new to android development. The errors on line 26 of my DBHleper class below. - String dbPath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static  final String DATABASE_NAME = "Database.db";
private static  final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public DBHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);

}

public void openDatabase(){
    String dbPath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
    if(mDatabase!= null && mDatabase.isOpen()){
        return;
    }
    mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

public Cursor getItems(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    qb.setTables("Attraction");

    Cursor c = qb.query(db,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    return c;
}
```

}

My main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DBHelper newDB;
private Cursor attraction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    newDB = new DBHelper(this);
    newDB.openDatabase();
    attraction = newDB.getItems();

}
```

}

I am probably having a mental block and not seeing the solution but any more help on this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).